# Andengine collision detection according to scaled size of sprite

Tags: andengine, collision-detection, sprite

I had Animated Sprites and i scaled down thoes sprites .. And increase the size of sprites. I want to detect collision of sprites according to scaled size.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can do in this way:

For Example

```
    Sprite player, monister;
          if( player.cotains(monister.getScaleX(), monister.getScaleY())){
              // you can do what ever you want
}
```